# Checking if BIND was compiled with dnstap support

Tags: debian, bind

I need [dnstap](https://kb.isc.org/article/AA-01342/0/Using-DNSTAP-with-BIND-9.11.html) support in BIND, for doing some debugging to the queries answers, and possibly statistics in a very near future.

How to check if in Debian9, the `bind9` package was compiled with support for `dnstap`?

See related: [DNS query response logging](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/408652/dns-query-response-logging/408654)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, as per the link provided in the question:

> dnstap will be generally available in BIND 9.11 but is in certain
>   editions of earlier versions, such as BIND 9.9.8-S5

So being BIND in Debian 9, v9.10.x, we can pretty much assume it has no `dnstap` support.

Furthermore, a recent bug ticket for Debian testing is asking for compiling it with DNS support.

[Bug#890483: bind9: compile with dnstap support](https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg1584702.html)

Nevertheless, you can also check the compile time options with `named -V`. There is no `--enable-dnstap` option in Stretch there.

```
$ named -V
BIND 9.10.3-P4-Debian <id:ebd72b3>
built by make with '--prefix=/usr' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--sysconfdir=/etc/bind' '--with-python=python3' '--localstatedir=/' '--enable-threads' '--enable-largefile' '--with-libtool' '--enable-shared' '--enable-static' '--with-gost=no' '--with-openssl=/usr' '--with-gssapi=/usr' '--with-gnu-ld' '--with-geoip=/usr' '--with-atf=no' '--enable-ipv6' '--enable-rrl' '--enable-filter-aaaa' '--enable-native-pkcs11' '--with-pkcs11=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/softhsm/libsofthsm2.so' '--with-randomdev=/dev/urandom' 'CFLAGS=-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/bind9-zVMG3I/bind9-9.10.3.dfsg.P4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -DNO_VERSION_DATE -DDIG_SIGCHASE' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' 'CPPFLAGS=-Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2'
compiled by GCC 6.3.0 20170516
compiled with OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
linked to OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
compiled with libxml2 version: 2.9.4
linked to libxml2 version: 20904
```

From `man named`:

> -V
>   Report the version number and build options, and exit.

As per the patches submitted with the bug report mentioned above, in the debian control file you can see the new suggested dependencies, `python3-ply`, `protobuf-c-compiler`, and `libfstrm-dev`.

Checking with `apt-cache showpkg bind9` there also are not in the dependencies listed for Stretch.

From looking at the list of dependencies in `bind9` for Buster/testing at https://packages.debian.org/buster/bind9, version 9.11.2.P1-1, it is also evident `bind9` is also not compiled with `dnstap` enabled in the testing branch.

So it can be said Debian BIND `dnstap` functionality is not supported by the BIND version in the Debian stable branch, and BIND in the Debian testing branch is not (still?) compiled to enable it.

P.S. As GAD3R correctly points out, you can also get with `apt-src` the source package to check the `./configure` directive in debian/rules from the bind9 package. (or go to github? cannot find the *Debian* bind9 official address)

Comment: You can check the build option under `debian/rules`.